# how import an enum in another enum

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I need to import enum A in enum B so i do:

```
export enum A{
HOME_A="home"
}
```

and in enum B I do :

```
export enum B{
HOME_B:A.HOME_A
}
```

but I obtain this exception:

```
Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the B enum, use `=` instead of `:`. So it will be `export enum B { HOME_B = A.HOME_A }`.

Here's an [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t6lqsc).

Good luck!

Comment: Dragos I edit my code but it gives me the same error damn! I read your example and it is umbeliveble that it doesn't work

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using? You can check it out in the package.json file.

Comment: the current version is 3.8.3

Comment: Weird. Does your code look exactly like what you pasted?

Comment: i modify my project and it similar to this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wuxfaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: But it work in stack blitz e not in my project! I think the only difference is the path vwhere I put my file?